# Ubuntu server on VirtualBox 

Tags: server, virtualbox

I have two network adapters on VirtualBox  for Ubuntu server.

- Adapter 1: internal network called intent
- Adapter 2: NAT

I want to configure them as follows,

- static IP 192.168.10.101 for the internal network adapter
- netmask 255.255.255.0
- dhcp IP for the NAT adapter

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you should ask at superuser.

Answer (score 6):

Open `/etc/network/interfaces` with your favorite text editor, ie:

> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

Locate the interfaces and set them as desired, ie:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.10.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

That should be all.